# is the best option use a thumbnail creator? or is better use styles? for a maximum size on image

Tags: php, html, css

Just a quick question, I have a fixed space in my site (100px x 210px) to include an image that user will upload (be aware that user can upload any image with any size)

I can show smaller images, but I can not display images that are greater than 100px x 210px (table issues)

Can you recommend me the best option? use a thumbnail creator script in PHP or use styles? like:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 210px;"/>
```

I really appreciate your recommendations and thanks in advance

Comment: Actually you can have both at same time.
But if you could apply only one solution, I'll prefer using thumbnail creator because transfer thumbnail consumes less bandwidth. This will be more significant benefit if your table contains lots of images and often-loaded. Of course you'll need extra space to save those thumbnails but it should worth from long term view, and thumbnails shouldn't take much disk spaces. Btw I'll suggest to create thumbnail right after user uploads their image.

Comment: Thanks HZS for your recomendation, I really appreciate
look like thumbnail creator is better for bandwidth consume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At the time of image upload, create a thumbnail image of size
   100X210 (if and only if image size is greater than >100X210.) & show them where you want to show. I think this is the best solution
2. At the time of showing the image, create the thumbnail of required size.( Not suggested.but if you have already a lot of uploaded image, then you can do it.But I will suggest to create a function & create the thumbnail back-end)